# Client & Backend deployed separately - 404 error page on refresh despite proxy configuration

Tags: express, deployment, proxy, http-status-code-404, vite

My project has a frontend and a backend deployed separately from 2 separate Github repos on "render.com".

*It also has a Mongoose database for user credentials. But it is not the subject of this question.*

All was working fine until I refreshed any page, I got 404 Not Found despite the configured proxy.

For instance, I redirect all my client-side links to "/" so that the user does not get the 404 Not Found page. At least it is more user friendly.

Here are some more details:

- Frontend is a **Vite react** client:
  Client Repo: `https://github.com/Catevika/catevika_shoplineart-client`
  Render static site: `https://shoplineart-afbr.onrender.com`
- Backend is an Express server:
  Server Repo: `https://github.com/Catevika/catevika_shoplineart-server`
  Render web service: `https://shoplineart-api.onrender.com`
- Routes are managed client-side with **react-router V6** but an authRoute for Login / Register.

**File structure**:

```
root
.. client
.. dist --> build folder with assets: pictures - ok in Render
.. src
.... api --> for Login
.... (...)
.. vite.config.js --> with proxy - ok in Render thanks to a Vite base URL variable
.. index.html --> outside "public" - specific to Vite
.. main.jsx
.. .env --> ok in Render
.. package.json

 .. server
 .. (...)
 .. index.js
 .. .env --> ok in Render
 .. package.json --> type: "module" to use the "import" instead of "require"
```

**vite.config.js**:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'https://shoplineart-api.onrender.com',
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [react()]
});
```

**Express index.js**:

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';
import path from 'path';

import authRoute from './routes/authRoute.js';

dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
console.log('\x1b[33m', 'MongoDB connected successfully');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: 'cross-origin' }));
app.use(morgan('common'));

app.use('/', authRoute);

app.listen(process.env.EXPRESS_PORT, () =>
    console.log('\x1b[33m', `Server running on port ${process.env.EXPRESS_PORT}`)
);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.get('*', (req, res) =>
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client', 'dist', 'index.html'))
    );
}
```

I tried adding `secure: false` in vite.config.js.
It failed.

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot for your precious help. I am stuck...